# what's the better translation of "you're out"?

Tags: expressions

like kids are playing an outdoor game and someone gets out.
How to say "you're out"?

Comment: Now when you say "gets out," I imagine you mean "gets out [of the game]," not "get out[doors]"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean someone is having an unsuccessful finish for the round, the word is 出局. You're out = 你出局了。